# Changing values from an array of one class withing another class

Tags: java, arrays, class, processing

I am a Processing-User and try to becoem a Eclipse-User.

This is my problem:

I have a boolean array in my main-class(I think this is what we call it) and a int array in a class. This is my metaphoric example:

```
public class myProblem extends PApplet{
    boolean[] boolArray = new boolean[10];
    public void setup(){
    }
    public void draw(){

    }
}

class myClass
{

    int[] intArray = new int[10];

    myClass()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<intArray.length;i++){
        intArray[i] = 100;
        boolArray[i] = true;
    }
}
```

How can change boolArray-Indices within myClass?

thank you for your support!

greetz

Comment: Please indent the code and follow java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `getter/setter` methods for `boolArray` in class `myProblem`  and use the getter to get the array and operate on it in your class `myClass`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...

I am trying right now, but it is that that the method is undefined for myClass.